# Flux integral/notation of position vector

Tags: multivariable-calculus

"Find the flux of $\mathbb{F} = \frac{m\vec{r}}{|\vec{r^3}|}$ out of the surface of the cube $0\leq x,y,z\leq a$ "

Two questions regarding this: When I first "solved" it, I considered $\vec{r}$ the position vector of the "side" I was currently calculating the flux out of, so for instance the bottom side would have had $\vec{r} = <x,y,0>$. This was apparently not correct though, and I was supposed to have interpreted it as $\vec{r} = <x,y,z>$ or $\vec{r} = x\mathbb{i} + y\mathbb{j} + z\mathbb{k}$ for all sides (In each calculation of the flux, $\vec{r}$ would have been the same.)

How could I have reached this conclusion? My first thought before starting was that $\vec{r}$ was just the position vector of the entire surface, but that fell apart since it's a cube and is thus a composite of several surfaces (not just one single surface)! Hence, it should be the only one you can logically know, which would be the position vector of the surface you are working with at any given time.

Secondly, I recognize the $x + y +z$ as the centroid, and the solution manual notes that "becuse of symmetry" the flux is equal out of all sides. My thinking is that this is becuse the flux is originating at the centroid of the cube, and is thus symmetrical out of the whole. Is that a decent description of what's going on? But then again, wouldn't  $\mathbb{F} = \frac{m\vec{r}}{|\vec{r^3}|}$ go to zero as you approach the origin, but not as you approach the point $<a,a,a>$, which would mean that the integral (and thus the flux) would be zero at the origin but not at the opposite corner $<a,a,a>$ (which wouldn't be symmetrical)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your first thought was correct. On the surface, the position vector should be where it is. For example, it is $(x,y,0)$ on the bottom and $(x,y,a)$ on the top.

Now think about the normal vector of those surfaces. For example, the normal is $(0,0,-1)$ on the bottom, and $(0,0,1)$ on the top.

After doing dot product, you will see that all three surface with $x,y,z=a$ have the same flux, and all three surface with $x,y,z=0$ have the same flux, because of "symmetry".